# Connecting yup and react-hook-form names when using array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

##### I'm trying to connect `react-hook-form` with `yup`'s schema via `register`, but am encountering an error. My aim is to pass a name along the lines of `exampleArray${index}.exampleProp` since I'll be rendering the inputs in a loop.

A simple example:

```
import * as yup from "yup";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  exampleArr: yup.array().of(
    yup.object().shape({
      exampleProp: yup.string()
    })
  )
});

type FormValues = yup.InferType<typeof schema>;

export default function App() {
  const methods = useForm<FormValues>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });
  return (
    <input type="text" {...methods.register("exampleArr[0].exampleProp")} /> // error here
  );
}
```

> Argument of type '"exampleArr[0].exampleProp"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"exampleArr" | `exampleArr.${number}` | `exampleArr.${number}.exampleProp`'.

example in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-orla-97p8m2?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell what type the `exampleArr.${number}` is:

As an example i just tested this on your sandbox and it worked fine:

```
<input type="text" {...methods.register("exampleArr[0].exampleProp" as any)} />
```

Comment: any way to do it without loosing the type safety?